# How to position color bar in GrADS?

Tags: grads

I am looking for a code which positions the color bar by itself. Here is graph:

[image]

I used the `set_pareas.gs` script to fix the graphs in columns and `color.gs` script to color the plots. The color bar script is `xcbar.gs`. Here are the command lines

```
c
set_parea 1 3 1 1 -margin 0.8
color 0 12 1.2 -kind red->orange->yellow->dodgerblue->blue
d var1
set_parea 1 3 1 2 -margin 0.8
color 0 12 1.2 -kind red->orange->yellow->dodgerblue->blue
d var2
set_parea 1 3 1 3 -margin 0.8
color -12 12 2.4 -kind blue->white->red
d var1-var2
```

I would like that the color bar stay just below the differences map and red->orange->yellow->dodgerblue->blue color bar stay just below the orange maps.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the position of color bar in the command of `xcbar`.

The below document maybe necessary for you:

http://kodama.fubuki.info/wiki/wiki.cgi/GrADS/script/xcbar.gs?lang=en